# SPARQL-query to select classes with multiple hasQuality

Tags: sparql, protege

I have ontology opened in Protege. On the tab Entities -> Object Properties you can see that object BOX_1 has two hasQuality: RED and GREEN. What sparql-query can return BOX_1 as the object that has more than 1 hasQuality? [here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRKAv.png)

Comment: you have to use the aggregate function `count` which means you also have to apply grouping via `group by` in SPARQL. then you also want to filter by an aggregate expression which takes `having` into account. something like `select ... (count(...) as ?cnt) where { ... } group by ... having (?cnt > 1)`

Comment: I undarstand that.. the problem is I don't how to write this query. can you give me an example how to select the object that has more than 1 hasQuality?

Comment: I have shown you the query template. You have to simply add the triple patterns which basically means, a variable you want to select as well as the property and object value URIs - and those URI are in your ontology, I do not have your data ...